# Sample Selection

Tags: inference

Imagine a company has designed a new user interface. The company has 1000 clients. They handpick 100 of their large clients to come and try the new user experience. Out of this 100 clients, 50 of them agree and test the user interface and after the testing period, their conversion rates improved by 30 percent (on average relative to the other 900 clients who were not invited). Is that a good estimate of conversion rate improvement for all large clients? what statistical methods can I use to adjust my estimate?

Comment: Question is unclear, what is conversion rate and how did you estimate it? What do you mean by "good estimate"? "Adjust" in what way?